# Problema al acceder a un post a traves de una imagen Django

Tags: python, django

en la pagina que estoy haciendo, quiero que al apretar en la foto de unos de los posts redireccione hacia el detail, que ahi muestra solo ese posts. Dejo los codigos.

post_card.html

```
<a href="{% url 'posts:detail:<posts.pk>' %}">
    <img style="width: 100%;" src="{{ post.photo.url }}" >
</a>
```

urls.py

```
path(
    route='posts/<int:pk>/',
    view=views.PostDetailView.as_view(),
    name='detail'
),
```

Comment: Esta mal el template tag `url`, debes pasarle los argumentos de la siguiente manera: `{% url 'posts:detail' post.pk %}`, no como lo muestras.

Comment: @JulioCesar, esta bien! Ponlo como respuesta y lo marco!

Comment: Acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta mal el *template tag* [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url), (recuerda que dicho *template tag* **genera URL's**, y según veo lo estas tratando como una "URL", lo cual esta mal), debes hacerlo de la  siguiente manera:

```
{% url 'posts:detail' post.pk %}
```

El primer argumento es un **nombre de patrón de URL**. Los argumentos adicionales deben ser valores separados por espacios que se utilizarán como argumentos en la URL (que serian argumentos **posicionales**)

Otra forma seria usar la **sintaxis de palabras clave** (tiene un poco mas de legibilidad):

```
{% url 'posts:detail' pk=post.pk %}
```

Cualquiera de las dos es valida, espero haberte ayudado.